# phpmyadmin html connect

Tags: php, javascript

i am currently creating a web application. the problem here it is coded purely in HTML and JScript. Is it possible to use a php script as well to connect to PHPmyadmin? i have been encountering the same problem where the script is being displayed as text file

Comment: You want to connect to **phpMyAdmin** or **mySql**? _phpMyAdmin_ is just a manager for mySql.

Comment: You need to have some server like Apache installed to parse PHP pages. Moreover, you will be connecting to MySQL, not phpMyAdmin for accessing data from database.

Comment: Where is your application's library? Is it running on a server?

Answer (score 2):

In fact phpMyAdmin is a software tool written in PHP, intended to handle the administration of MySQL over the World Wide Web.
I think you want to make databases so you should use MySQL directly.

Surely you can use PHP . but

If you will be using php then clear it in your mind that PHP is server oriented language and can only be parsed by a server like Apache . So it will be overhead for you if you are using only HTML and JScript.

Comment: Accept the answer if you got it.

Comment: okay cool. so is it possible if i just run apache from xampp?

Comment: yes xampp is a package of Apache , MySQL and some utilities. It is perfectly right if you use xampp for Apache. :)

Comment: hey sorry again. i have been getting this problem where the php script is being displayed as text in my webpage. any ideas why?

Comment: webpage is rendered by browser and browser can only render HTML not php. So, the server as Apache convert the PHP into HTML and send it to rendered in browser. So, clear it in your mind that PHP script cannot be displayed in webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is a server side scripting language, you need to have a server such as apache or tomcat. And yeah, you can use a php file to access the mysql database.